# Android, how to send email through adb shell?

Tags: python, shell, email, adb, monkeyrunner

I am using monkeyrunner to run some tests on Android devices. I have a python script in which I create contacts and I use this shell for that:

```
device.shell("am start -a android.intent.action.INSERT -t vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact -e name '"+name+"' -e phone "+number+"")
```

Now I need to do something similar for Gmaul, I need to make an automated test using monkeyrunner to send several email messages using Gmail. I want to use an intent to populate the email fields (from, to, subject...), however I cant figure out how to do it.

Please, does anyone know how to start an Intent for Gmail?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

It is pretty easy to compose and send an email through gmail using `adb`, here are the steps:

1. Open the gmail intent passing the "to", "subject" and "body" fields:

   ```
   adb shell am start -n com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ComposeActivityGmail -d email:address@destination.com --es subject 'Your subject goes here' --es body 'Your email body goes here'
   ```

   At this point you will have your Gmail apk opened with your email data filled up.
2. Send the email

   In order to send the email you just need to navigate to the send button of your gmail apk:

   ```
   adb shell input keyevent 19 (3x) (dpad up)
   adb shell input keyevent 23 (dpad center)
   ```

Thats it!

Comment: Hi, I want to ask about the input keyevent, is it the same on all versions of Android? Can you please give me more info about why keyevent 19 is executed three times? Thanks in advance.
I'm currently using your solution although I would like to understand what you did there.

Answer (score 0):

**[AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient)** can help you with your task. Specifically, one of the **examples** provided with the source code is [email-send.py](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient/blob/master/AndroidViewClient/examples/email-send.py) that will set you on the right direction.